# ASP classic active directory query permissions issue. ASP error 80072020

Tags: iis, asp-classic, active-directory, kerberos

I have a ASP classic intranet site running on Windows 2003 with IIS 6. Before you ask why its a site, I inherited the site and at present it cannot be changed. I'm trying to convert a part of site that does a look up on an old database that needs to go away to instead look up a user in AD and give permissions based on if they are a member of a security group. The code I have works using VBscript to search for the user in AD and grab their group memberships.  The issue I have appears to be a double hop or permissions issue in IIS that blocks me. Here is my code:

```
<%
Dim sLogonUser : sLogonUser = Request.ServerVariables("Logon_User")
Dim sDomain : sDomain = Mid(sLogonUser, 1, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") - 1)
Dim sLogonName : sLogonName = Mid(sLogonUser, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") + 1)

response.write sDomain
response.write sLogonName
' Create ADO connection to Active Directory
'
Dim oConnection
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With oConnection
    .Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    .Mode = "1" 'Read
    .Properties("Encrypt Password") = True 
    .Open "Active Directory Provider"
End With

' Create command to search user in Active Directory
'
Dim oCommand
Set oCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection

' Build the ADsPath element of the CommandText
'
Dim oRoot
Dim oDomain
Dim sADsPath
Dim sFilter
Dim sAttribsToReturn
Dim sDepth
Dim oRS
Dim i
Dim value
Dim c_EmployeeDirectoryConnectionString


Set oRoot = GetObject("LDAP://" & sDomain & "/rootdse")
Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & sDomain & "/" & oRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
sADsPath = "<" & oDomain.ADsPath & ">"

' Build the filter element of the CommandText
'
sFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & sLogonName & "))"

' Build the returned attributes element of the CommandText
'
sAttribsToReturn = "distinguishedName,memberOf"

' Build the depth element of the CommandText
'
sDepth = "subTree"

' Assemble the CommandText
'
ocommand.CommandText = sADsPath & ";" & sFilter & ";" & sAttribsToReturn & ";" & sDepth

' Execute the query
'
Set oRS = ocommand.Execute

' Only one user should meet the criteria
'
If (oRS.RecordCount = 1) Then
    ' Get that user's info
    '
    oRS.MoveFirst
    For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1

        ' memberOf
        '
        If (oRS.Fields(i).Name = "memberOf") Then
            ' adVariant
            '
            For Each value In oRS.Fields(i).Value
                if Instr(value, "testgroup") <> 0 then
                response.write "member of testgroup"
                End If
            Next


        End If
    Next


End If
%>
```

When you run the code you get the user correctly but when it goes to look them up to AD it fails with error: `'80072020' <iis site path>/test.asp, line 44`

I get the error when run both locally on the webserver or remotely from my machine. The web server is configured with integrated windows auth. Anonymous authentication is off and the site is set up with a application pool identity running as a domain service account.  I don't know enough about IIS to know what the issue is but I assume I have something set up wrong. If I hard code a user name and run under anonymous authentication it will look up the user just fine. Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out to be a kerberos issue.  The IIS site was not properly configured to use kerberos.  So when a user loaded the page it would take their domain login name from windows authentication and try to pass that to AD and since all users have read rights on the domain they should be able to look up group memberships. but since it was not using kerberos it could not send the credentials to AD to do the query.

Adding SPNs for the IIS webserver and the domain account running the application pool then setting the service account to be trusted for kerberos authentication fixed the issue.

I used this thread as a reference:  [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84641/how-to-read-active-directory-group-membership-from-php-iis-using-com)

And I used this tool to help me trouble shoot kerberos: [Kerberos Delegation utility for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/delegconfig-v2-beta-%28delegation-kerberos-configuration-tool%29)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving IUSR_machinename and IWAM_machinename full change permissions to the relevant folders?